# add key value pair of objects in an array

Tags: javascript

```
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var family = []

var people = {alice:40, bob:42, michelle:8, timmy:6};


for (var key in people) {
  family.push({key:people[key]})
}

console.log(family);
```

This is not giving me the keys. its giving 'key' for each key.
what is the proper way to add {key:value} pair of objects in an array?

***UPDATE***
Based on K3N solution below, this is what i understood works best if we are declaring from a constructor each time:

```
keys = Object.keys(people);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  family.push(new Person(keys[i], people[keys[i]]));
}
```

Comment: who ever down votes, specify your reason so i can add whatever info you are looking for

Comment: Note that for-in loops are considerable slower than a normal for-loop.

Comment: @K3N thanks, that will be further optimization. will make sure. the answer to this problem was to fix the output which i wasn't getting at first

Comment: @user2290820 the approach you have used seems closer to K3N instead of  mine as you have not used square notation instead passed the key as argument to constructor, so i think you should not accept mine answer

Comment: @Ankit I get your point. I think torex put it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your people arrays contains name of the person as key, and value being the age (be careful as if you get two persons with the same name nuclear reaction in time-space happens...!).

You can do it like this:

```js
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var family = []

var people = {alice:40, bob:42, michelle:8, timmy:6};

var keys = Object.keys(people);               // list all (ownProperty) keys in object
for(var i = 0, key; key = keys[i]; i++) {     // loop through
  family.push(new Person(key, people[key]));  // push it
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(family));       // demo output
```

Comment: @torox it is as well as the the other one. i selected this one first. the other one is elegant. but the changes like family.push(new Person(key, people[key])); were made later. anyhow i wasnt looking to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

Wither use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) so that key can be treated as a variable property name

```
for (var key in people) {
    var temp={};
    temp[key]=people[key]
    family.push(temp)
}
```

Or [Computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
for (var key in people) {
  family.push({[key]:people[key]})
}
```

Comment: this is not efficient. i see var created at every iteration

Comment: This is better. so you include the key ina bracket. why does that work?